# Question related to conditional probability

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

An office building is equipped with a single entrance that everybody must take to either enter or leave the building. A people counting sensor is installed at this entrance. Every time a person enters or leaves the building, the sensor registers a detection event. In all other circumstances, the sensor does not register any detection event. Each detection event is labelled as either IN or OUT. When one person enters the building, the sensor labels the associated detection event as IN with 0.9 probability. When one person leaves the building, the sensor labels the associated detection event as OUT with 0.94 probability. On December 16th, 2019, the sensor registered 100 detection events having occurred before 7 p.m. It is also known that on that day the building was empty before 6 a.m. and that at 7 p.m. there were 6 people inside the building.

1.A detection event having occurred on December 16th, 2019 before 7 p.m. is drawn at random. What is the probability that this event was triggered by a person having actually left the building?

2.A detection event having occurred on December 16th, 2019 before 7 p.m. is drawn at random. If the sensor has labelled this event as IN, what is the probability that it was triggered by a person having actually entered the building?

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and indicate which aspects of the problem are preventing you from solving it. Otherwise, the question is likely to get closed as solving others' homeworks is not the purpose of this forum.